# 3D Screenspace Raycasting/Picking DirectX9

Tags: c++, matrix, 3d, directx, raycasting

I need to convert a 2D mouse coordinate to a 3D world coordinate based on a specific depth (it's for raycasting). I'm not directly using DirectX in C++, I'm using a proprietary language, but if you give me an answer in C++ or pseudocode (C++ preferred) I can convert it.

I have access to the world matrix, view matrix and projection matrix and a variety of matrix manipulation functions.

If it's necessary to multiply a vector4 by a matrix4, the only function I have available that takes both a vector4 and a matrix4 is `transformVector4(vector4Source,matrix4Source)`. I'm not sure which order it multiplies them in, if that matters.

Any help would be much appreciated :) I've been working on this for hours and I just don't get 3D maths...

Comment: calculate the ray on eye coordinate for your camera first(using some trigs) then transform that ray into world coordinate by multiplying with the inverse of modelview matrix of the camera.

Comment: @yngum: It's easier to transform the target object coordinates into screen space (which is already done for rendering purposes anyway), and do hit-testing in 2D.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes I imagine that works too. op is asking for world coordinate so I thought of the straight forward way that myself have been doing.

Comment: I don't have the faintest clue how to do the first comment-answer. Could you elaborate a bit more? Be specific? I don't know the target object coordinates (that's what I'm trying to calculate) and I have no access to low-level rendering stuff. Also, I need to have a start point (just the camera's position) and an end point and it must be a 3D raycast. I have tools for the raycasting itself, just not for calculating where the mouse cursor is in 3D. @yngum has the right idea, just not explained clearly. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Clonkex The answer is little long because I am not sure about your understanding of 3d transformation. You should google a bit, this is a frequent question and there should be plenty of tutorials. like [this one](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/selection.htm#sele0010)

Comment: @yngum I barely understand matrices. All I wanted was some C++ or pseudocode. I have Googled it extensively but all of the tutorials and answers so far have been specific to OpenGL (most of them), not worked for me or been incomplete answers. [This page](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6940/3d-ray-casting-picking) is the closest I gotten to a good answer, but it has some errors in the code and I'm not sure how it's supposed to look. Plus, why would I need a ModelView matrix for a camera? Why not just a View matrix? Is there even a difference?

Comment: @Clonkex the model matrix is for when your camera is placed not at the origin but otherwise unnecessary. Your link is basically how it work and is simpler.

Comment: @Clonkex check out [this tutorial](http://www.bfilipek.com/2012/06/select-mouse-opengl.html)

Comment: @yngum That's what I mean by OpenGL-specific. I can't use that tutorial because the most important bit, converting 2d to 3d, is handled by an OpenGL-specific function, gluUnProject. I'll do some more experimenting with modelview matrix now, but I doubt that I will succeed with anything... Remember, my link shows a broken method of calculating the 2d-3d conversion and I don't know what to do to make it correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert you mouse to ray, you do this process:

Convert your mouse coordinates from pixel coordinate to -1/1 coordinates (-1,-1 being bottom left).

ray origin will be (vector at near plane)

```
vector3 origin = vector3(mousex,mousey,0);
```

ray end is (vector at far plane)

```
vector3 far = vector3(mousex,mousey,1);
```

now you need to apply transform to those vectors, first you need to create transformation matrix for it:

```
matrix4x4 inverseviewproj = invertmatrix(view * proj)
```

Apply this transformation to both vectors:

```
vector3 rayorigin = transform(origin, inverseviewproj);
vector3 rayend = transform(far, inverseviewproj);
```

Your ray direction is :

```
vector3 raydirection = normalize(rayend-rayorigin);
```

That's about it, now you can use raycast functions.

In case you only have access to vector4 to transform vector by a matrix,
the w component needs to be 1 in eg:

```
vector4 origin = vector3(mousex,mousey,0,1);
vector4 far = vector3(mousex,mousey,1,1);
```

to extract direction make sure to first convert your vector4 into vector3 (since it will affect normalization otherwise).

Comment: PERFECT! Thankyou! THAT'S what I was looking for! Clean, clear and to the point. AND it works! Very pleased, thankyou so much! :D

Comment: How about when there's a world transform ?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis normally when there is a world transform for an object, you transform the ray by the invert of it